# Which Gobject Type for datetime and decimal in Python Gtk3

Tags: python, gtk3, gobject

I want to create a Gtk.ListStore for the types:

- datetime.date(2015, 8, 24)
- Decimal('24.28')

How can I find out which type to choose?

I found a few types here: https://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/stable/class-gtkliststore.html

But not sure what is the best to choose.

Thanks

edit: now I convert them to string to get it working. But is this the best solution?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you can use `GObject.TYPE_PYOBJECT` for any Python object.

Answer (score 0):

For Decimal('24.28'), I would use a float (gfloat). For anything datetime, I use a string.